# Use SSH to execute robot framework test

Tags: ssh, robotframework

I user SSH to execute robot framework testcases (selenium), but there is no browser opened, the testcases is executed in the background? How can I solve this issue?

I want to execute robot framework testcases on win10, and I want to start the test via Jenkins which is installed on Linux, so I installed a SSH plugin in the Jenkins, then I create a job in Jenkins and execute below command via SSH

```
pybot.bat --argumentfile E:\project\robot_framework\Automation\logs\argfile1.txt E:\project\robot_framework\Automation
```

when I start the job, the testcase is executed in the background, but I need the test case to open the browser in the front.

Comment: Need more information. Why are you expecting `ssh` to open a browser window? What kind of system are you on? What command are you executing? Are you invoking a browser with `ssh`? What relationship do the test cases have with the browser? This question needs some clarity.

Comment: Blind stab in the dark... use ssh -X ? But I have no idea what you're asking, please try again

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] so that we can help you better?

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the Linux server is running Jenkins and connects to the Windows 10 box to run Robot Framework test there? Robot and it's tests are located on the Windows 10 box and you have an SSH connection from Linux to Windows 10. Can you explain what you mean 'in the background'?

Comment: I'm still struggling with what you mean by "browser".  Do you mean web browser, like Firefox or Chrome? If so, this doesn't make too much sense; normally one would run a browser locally and connect to the box over http, not over ssh. (I believe this is how Jenkins normally works.) Ssh is for issuing command-line programs. If by browser you mean some sort of GUI, you would need to run a local X server on the Windows box such as Cygwin/X (www.cygwin.org) and use the `ssh -X` option to see it. But then I don't understand where the automation comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh by definition executes commands in a different session than the current user's.
Especially considering your target is a Windows machine - imagine if you were logged in and working with desktop apps, and someone starts an app through ssh in your session - would be a little surprising (mildly put :), wouldn't it?

To get what you want - being able to monitor the execution, you could try `runas /user:username` command, but a satisfactory end result is not guaranteed (plus you have to provide the target user's password).
Another option is to use `psexec`, available on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), but YMMV - you have to provide the target session id, some programs might not show up - or might not be maximizable, etc. The call format would be

```
psexec.exe -i 2 pybot.bat the_rest_of_the_args
```

I.e. a lot of effort and uncertainties, with minimal ROI :)

Comment: I solve my issue by create scheduled task on the Windows, thanks anyways